# jQuery Mobile stops working if I remove the css file

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile to create a list menu.

I use a 'slide' effect, when you click an

element to show the next page.

I was using a css style sheet which had too many design elements.
So I went ahead and removed the stylesheet and instead added the required styling in the html document.

But now the slide effect doesn't work if I click the

elements.

If I include the css style sheet, then it starts working again.

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/r24XY/ code.

Comment: That's because the stylesheet handles the animation. Take a look at the source version: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.css, and search for animation.

Comment: @MikeRobinson there is too much code, is there a better alternative?

Comment: don't use jQuery UI/Mobile would be a nice alternative in my opinion.

Comment: You need to start by asking yourself what you want from the framework... There are lots of great micro-frameworks out there that have been specifically designed for mobile web development. Ripping  one apart file by file to fit your needs is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. You can use a framework, or not. If not, take some time to learn how CSS3 animations work. They're pretty simple and worth knowing about.

Comment: I'm trying to build a css iPod. I've got the layout done, I'm using jQuery mobile just to get the menu slide effect (when you select a menu item). Take a look at this.
http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/iPod
@MikeRobinson

Comment: @BenM I just want a slide effect when the user selects a menu item. I'm building an iPod classic in CSS, see above comment for link.

Comment: You're using a whole library for a CSS transition? There's no wonder that it contains a lot of code you don't need!

Comment: @BenM :P I thought it'd be a quick way to get the list menu working.

Comment: @user461844 Looks pretty cool. If you're trying to build a CSS project anyway, might as well learn about CSS3 animation. You could learn to code the animations yourself in the time it takes to rip them out of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @MikeRobinson thanks man, the final version will have html5 audio playback too. For this project, I guess i'll go with jQuery (no mobile) for the animation.

Answer (score 2):

The whole reason why you see those cool looking animations is because of that CSS file.
You must have both JQuery Mobile .js and .css library files in order for things to move.

Ripping certain elements out of the library CSS files just to build your own is a bad idea, very bad idea. What if you miss something ? Even if you don't.. what if they release an update tomorrow? You're going to have to maintain a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

CSS animations (or transitions / transforms) are used in jQuery Mobile and other mobile web frameworks since these are hardware accelerated on certain devices (namely iOS). Thus, removing the CSS file of course removes the animations.